# Vue.js - concatenation

Tags: javascript, laravel, vue.js, vuejs2, require

I have a very strange problem.

All this code below is **working fine** :

```
    payload.modules.forEach(function(mod) {

        var modules_path = '../../modules/';

        // Routes
        router.addRoutes(require('../../modules/'+mod.module_id+'/routes.js'));
        // Store
        store.registerModule(['modules', mod.module_id],
    require('../../modules/'+mod.module_id+'/store.js').default);

    });
```

But when I use the **modules_path** variable into my require like this  :

```
    payload.modules.forEach(function(mod) {

        var modules_path = '../../modules/';

        // Routes
        router.addRoutes(require(modules_path+mod.module_id+'/routes.js'));
        // Store
        store.registerModule(['modules', mod.module_id],
    require('../../modules/'+mod.module_id+'/store.js').default);

    });
```

At this moment, that doesn't work.
What can explains that ?
That seems to be the same for me.

Thanks for your help  :)

---

**Edit :**

```
        var modules_path = '../../modules/clients/routes.js';

        // Routes
        router.addRoutes(require(modules_path));
```

Does the same as well. Type of modules_path is string.

Comment: What is the data type of `mod.module_id`?

Comment: I'm not sure why it happens, but you could look into [aliasing](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/resolve/) common folders.

Comment: That is the same with :

var modules_path = '../../modules/clients/routes.js';

      // Routes
      router.addRoutes(require(modules_path));


type of modules_path is string naturally

Answer (score 1):

You can try adding `.toString()` to `mod.module_id` or `modules_path.concat(mod.module_id.toString().concat('/routes.js'));`

Comment: May i also ask, why you're loading files like that instead of using laravel mix?

Comment: Because this a dynamic and modular application which load user's modules when login

Comment: I'm curious, why would `.concat()` work and `+` not?

Comment: my guess has to do with variable types but the + should work no matter the type